# Medicamentous vs medical

Tags: meaning, word-usage, synonyms

Are the adjectives  medicamentous and medical  synonymous? Clarification regarding minute difference between them and their usage will be appreciated.

I ask this question in the score that I  couldn't see a subtle or  clear- cut difference in their meanings, as suggested by dictionaries,which are mostly  converging...

Comment: I had to check definitions to convince myself that _medicamentous_ was even a real word. It is, but it's a pretty rare one. I note that all the examples supplied by [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/medicamentous) are by Eastern European authors. Note also that not all _medical_ treatment involves _medicines_.

Comment: I have hardly ever seen  the usage of term medicament wheresoever in modern medical field. So, my humble guess is  medicamentous treatment is linked to some other medical practices.

Comment: It would be a good name for a brand of throat mints or other medicated sweet/candy.

Comment: medicamentous sounds like a bad translation of médicamenteux (French}.

Answer (score 1):

[As MW explains,](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/medicine) *medicine* can mean two things: "a substance or preparation used in treating disease" or "the science and art dealing with the maintenance of health and the prevention, alleviation, or cure of disease." In the former sense, the corresponding adjective is *medicinal*; in the latter sense, the adjective is *medical.*

By contrast, the far more obscure word [*medicament*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/medicament) has only the former of these two meanings: it means "a substance used in therapy." As you note, the corresponding adjective is *medicamentous.*

So *medicamentous* is a synonym of *medicinal,* not *medical.*

Comment: Well... It Sounds good...

Comment: That would be a matter of taste. To me, it sounds awful.

Comment: Synonyms only have a range of overlap in meaning. 'Medicamentous' _is_ a synonym of 'medical' but with a lesser degree of correspondence. But it's also ghastly.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Do you have a source for that? I only found the definition of "medicamentous" listed above, i.e. "related to a medicine/drug."

Comment: How does the stress shift? Is it _MEDicamentous_ or _meDICamentous_, or  _medicaMENtous_? Has any living English speaker ever heard it pronounced? How would you discover what they heard?

Comment: @JohnLawler [MW lists two pronunciations](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/medicamentous); one with primary stress on the second syllable, the other with stress on the first.

Comment: (I can't help hearing it as some odd portmanteau of *medical + momentous*. Example usage: "The new treatment will be a truly medicamentous change for patients.")

Comment: @EdwinAshworth is back!

Comment: The word *medical* is sometimes used by medical professionals (but almost never by the general public) in a narrow sense that corresponds to the first sense of *medicine* listed in this answer; in that usage, medical treatment may be contrasted with, say, surgical treatment. *Medicamentous* could be used as a synonym of *medical* in that narrow sense, although it almost never is.

Comment: @jsw29 Another example is the phrase "medical marijuana." But this is fairly rare; one would usually say "medicinal herbs" rather than "medical herbs."

Answer (score 0):

> Are the adjectives medicamentous and medical synonymous?

No.

The comments have been very kind so far. Some might say "too kind".

I suspect that you have found this word in a dictionary that has not been amended in the last 150 years.

Unless you are a professor of some sort of medicine  you will not be using this word at all. The choice is therefore simple... or should have been, as it actually means "medicinal".

Use **medicinal**.

Seriously, OED states of medicamentous:

> This word belongs in Frequency Band 2. Band 2 contains words which occur fewer than 0.01 times per million words in typical modern English usage. These are almost exclusively terms which are not part of normal discourse and would be unknown to most people. Many are technical terms from specialized discourses. Examples taken from the most frequently attested part of the band include decanate, ennead and scintillometer (nouns)...

and gives

> Of the nature of a medicine, medicinal; involving a medicine;

It has an exact synonym: **medicamental** that is equally rare.